# Did I wire this AC motor properly?

Tags: motor, ac, induction, ac-motor

I disassembled a drill to replace the chuck and when putting it back together it seems to be short-circuiting. I have doubled check the cables but they seem to be ok, so I'm afraid I may have wired it wrongly.

The drill is very simple, it only contains a switch and a AC motor. Here is a photo of how I've connected the components:

[image: Picture of the circuit]

and here is a rough schematics of the circuit:

[image: schematics]

I suspect that the short circuit may be coming from the brushes, since they are both in contact with the commutator, the form a close circuit with the AC source, but I don't know how to connect them otherwise.

Comment: Can you reverse direction of it with a switch? If yes, the rotor and stator can not be in series. The commutator does not look happy.

Comment: Why do you think the motor is short circuited?

Comment: what is `seems to be short-circuiting`? ... how are you determining this?

Comment: the red wire looks suspicious ... it has two sharp bends where it rested against something ... it looks like it may be installed backwards ... if the red wire connects to a brush, then maybe the brushes are installed backwards

Comment: @winny No, I can't, the drill only has two positions on and off. What is the problem with  the commutator?

Comment: @JRE When I close it up and turn it on, I can see sparks inside the casing and there is a slight burn smell.

Comment: @jsotola I can see sparks inside the casing and there is a slight burn smell.

Comment: brushes can throw a lot of sparks if moved from their "settled in" position ... did you move them from their original orientation?

Comment: Does the motor turn?

Comment: One direction only could mean series connection of magnetizing (stator) and rotor or parallel. The armature commutator is burnt and worn. Please measure that you don’t have any short between any windings.

Comment: @jsotola Thanks, I followed you advice and indeed, I was installing the brushes backwards, I turned them around and now the motor works perfectly. 
I still see *some* sparks just after turning it on (though much less than before) but I guess that's normal.

Answer (score 1):

After reading the comments and some testing, I realised that, even though my schematics were correct, I was installing the brushes backwards. Turning the components around fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The wiring appears to be correct.

The problem may be related to the mechanical assembly.